# How to move 513MB healthy logical drive partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I have a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I want to reallocate 300GB from Windows to Ubuntu.

I have used Windows' disk management tool to unallocate 300GB but there is an intermittent partition between the newly unallocated space and my Ubuntu partition, labeled as "513MB Healthy Logical Drive D" which is FAT32 and cannot be moved using either Windows' tool or `gparted` on a live Ubuntu USB. Is this the partition where GRUB is stored?

When using `parted` on the Ubuntu side I see:

[image]

The partition that I refer to is Number 5 (Start 699GB, End 700GB) and is right before Number 6 (Start 700GB, End 1000GB) which is my Ubuntu partition. The unallocated space is labeled as Free Space (Start 384GB, End 699GB).

How could I bypass/move logical partition Number 5?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If it it possible to resize the extended partition (I think but not sure), then you could move that to the front right after the ntfs partition. That would actually move the free space into the extended partition. Then you could move logical partition 5 to the front of the extended partition and enlarge it into the free space.

Comment: thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with GParted if you boot into a live environment. The key is to extend partition 4. These are the steps:

1. Backup any data anywhere on the drive that you cannot afford to loose.
2. Boot into the live environment. (Try Ubuntu)
3. Using GParted resize partition 4 (it’s a container for partitions 3, 5 and 6). Move its start point next to partition 2. That will move the unallocated space inside partition 4. Apply the change.
4. Move partition 5 to the start of partition 4. That will move the unallocated space next to partition 6. Apply the change
5. Resize partition 6 to make use of the unallocated space. Apply the change.

That’s it. Reboot and your Linux partition should have more space available

Good luck

Comment: thanks, it solved it!